# $geoNear with condition parameter

Tags: arrays, mongodb, geolocation, operators

I have document in record collection Mongodb (3.4) like below :-

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("592d0c78555a7436b0883960"), 
  "userid" : 7, 
   "addresses" : [
    {
        "apporx" : 50.0, 
        "loc" : [
            -73.98137109999999, 
            40.7476039
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "apporx" : 15.0, 
        "loc" : [
            -73.982002, 
            40.74767
        ]          
    }, 
    {
        "apporx" :10.0, 
        "loc" : [
            -73.9819567, 
            40.7471609
        ]
    }
 ]
}
```

I created 2d index on this collection using below query :-

```
db.records.createIndex({ "addresses.loc": "2d" })
```

I want to use $geoNear command after conditional opearator but $geoNear must be a first in aggregate pipeline.Is there any other way,such that i can apply condition "addresses.loc" like 'addresses.loc' between 50 and 100. after applying this condition whatever elements fetched from 'addresses'array $geonear will apply on that elements.

Comment: You can provide a "query" parameter to [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/). As this is in an aggregation pipeline you can even do a `$match` at a later stage with a different effect. But *"What result are you expecting?"*. Notably your "locations" are in an array inside the document, so the combination of query options and a location argument in `$geoNear` will likely not return what you expect.

Comment: For example: The "near" query portion may be nearest to a certain array element. But there is actually no way to make any condition "combined" with the "near" part which specifies the condition on the "nearest array element". That is possible with a later `$match`, but the effect would be to "filter" rather than force selection of a different array element as nearest. So it really depends on what you are actually asking here. To make it clear you should include more than one sample document and show the expected result you want to return from some given conditions.